# stored procedure name to id translation

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I've a table `provider` which has `id|provider_name|url`
I've another table `user` which has `id|name|provider_id`

I want to create a function `create_user(name,provider_name)` that checks whether there exists any provider with that provider name. if exists insert the row and return last row id. other wise return `0`. I've set up foreign key integrity on `provider_id` -> `user.id`. and both `id` fields are `pkey` and `serial`

```
insert into users
  (name, provider_id)
values($1, (
    select id from provider where name = $2
)) returning id
```

Is that Okay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

```
INSERT INTO users (name, provider_id)
VALUES ($1, (SELECT id FROM provider WHERE name = $2))
RETURNING id;
```

will work if you make users.provider_id `NOT NULL`. Without that you would enter a `NULL` value for a non-existent provider_id. A foreign key constraint does not prohibit this!
(I assume you meant: `provider_id -> provider.id`, not `-> user.id`.)

You may or may not want to make `users.name UNIQUE` to prohibit duplicate names.

With unique names, a surrogate primary key (`user.id`) would still makes sense in most cases. Handling of an integer is faster than handling of a (longer) text. Especially if you have multiple other tables referencing the primary key of the `user` table which is normally the case. Using an integer for the foreign keys and accompanying indexes is considerably faster and needs less space on disk and in RAM. It is also easier to make changes later, like splitting the `name` into `firstname` and `surname`.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work if there are multiple user rows with that name.  If duplicate names among users is not possible, then it would be okay.  (If that's really a name, it doesn't seem wise to assume no duplicates are possible.)

Of course, if duplicate user names are not possible, there is no good reason to have an id column on the user table; I would strongly recommend just making name the primary key and leaving off the id column.  (It should possibly be called something else, too.)  That would simplify and speed this query, along with whole classes of queries.  This schema design also assumes that one user can have at most one provider (if provider_id is null capable) or exactly one provider (if provider_id is NOT NULL).